# how to update a update ListTiles in Listview based on a List in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, listview

I have this function:

```
Add_meal_to_list(String meal_title){

  MealModel instance1 = MealModel(meal_title);
  main_meal_list.add(instance1);
  print("modell wurde erstellt");
  print(main_meal_list[1].meal_title);

return main_meal_list; }
```

where i can add models to my list that works so far but the new added models are not shown in my Listview

```
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: displayed_meal_list.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: ListTile(
                
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            
            
            
           title:Text(displayed_meal_list[index].meal_title!),
              
               ),
            ) 
          )
        ),
```

the problem is probably that the Listview isnt updating his ListTiles, but i dont now wehre to add the setState function to fix it

full build i know its really messy and the circle Avatar thing is not important:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:grocery_app/create_new_meal.dart';
import 'package:grocery_app/meal_model.dart';
import 'package:grocery_app/search_page_meal.dart';
import 'package:grocery_app/shopping_list_homescreen.dart';

class meal_page extends StatefulWidget {
  const meal_page({super.key});

  @override
  State<meal_page> createState() => _meal_pageState();
}

class _meal_pageState extends State<meal_page> {


  Add_meal_to_list(String meal_title){
    
      MealModel instance1 = MealModel(meal_title);
      main_meal_list.add(instance1);
      print("modell wurde erstellt");
      print(main_meal_list[1].meal_title);
    
    return main_meal_list;
  }

  

  List<MealModel> displayed_meal_list = List.from(main_meal_list);

  


  int myIndex =  0; 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      title: Text("Mahlzeiten"),
      centerTitle: true,
      actions: <Widget> [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search), 
          
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push( context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => search_page_meal()));
          },
          ), 

      ],

    ),

    bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
      destinations: [
        Container(color:Colors.blue,),
        
        Container(
          
          
          //padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          color:Colors.red,
          child:Column(
            children: [
              GestureDetector( child:
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 50,
                icon:Icon(Icons.home),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(14),
                
                onPressed: () {
                  
                }, 
                 ),
               ),
               
            ],
          ),
           
          ),
        Container(
          color:Colors.pink,
          
            child: Column( 
              children: [
                IconButton(
                iconSize: 50,
                onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => shopping_list_homescreen())
              );
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.list),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(14),
            ),
              ],
             
          ),
         )
          
      ],

    ),
      
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      body: Column(
        children: [
        
            
          Expanded( 
              child:Padding( 
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded( 
                  child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  child: Column(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector( 
                      onTap: () {
                        
                      },
                    child:CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/Frühstück.jpg")
                      
                        
                        ),
                        ),
                        Text("Frühstück")
                         ]
                       ),
                      
                    )
                     ),
                  Expanded( 
                  child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  child: Column(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print("111");
                      },
                    child:CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/Frühstück.jpg"),
                      
                        
                        ),
                        
                         ),
                         Text("Frühstück")
                         ]
                          
                       ),
                      
                    )
                     ),
                    Expanded( 
                  child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  child: Column(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap:() {
                        
                      },
                    child:CircleAvatar(
                      
                      radius: 30,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/Frühstück.jpg"),
                      
                        
                        ),
                         ),
                        Text("Frühstück")
                         ]
                       ),
                      
                    )
                     )
                  ],
                )
                 )
                 ),
                
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: displayed_meal_list.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: ListTile(
                    
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  //leading: Image(image: AssetImage(displayed_meal_list[index].meal_image!)),
                  title: Text(displayed_meal_list[index].meal_title!),
                  //subtitle: Text("${displayed_meal_list[index].meal_time!} min" ),
                   ),
                ) 
              )
            ),


            
              
            



              ],
            ),
      
    
    
      
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton( 
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      
      highlightElevation: 10,
      autofocus: true,
      onPressed:() {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => create_new_meal(callback: Add_meal_to_list,))
        );
        
      },
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
      ),
        
        child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black,),
      
       
      ),
      
      


  );
 }
}
```

the String for the function add_meal_to_list im getting from the callback

Comment: Where are you adding items?  That should be what does the setState.  If it's a different widget, you'll need some form of observable data from state management.

Comment: You are calling `main_meal_list.add()` but you are rendering `displayed_meal_list`. Can you [edit] your question to include the full `build` method?

Comment: I'm adding the items in the add_meal_to_list function

Comment: Where are you using the `Add_meal_to_list()` function? Normally you just add `setState` right after you call the function.